# How to avoid error UNIQUE constraint failed when I save in cascade

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

I want to save my entity A witch has manyToOne relation with entity B.

The problem is, I want to save many different Entities A which contain the same entity B.

So, when I try:

```
session.save(A);
```

I have this hibernate error :

```
ERROR: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (UNIQUE constraint failed: B.id)
```

I see on other topic that people recommande to create a function :

```
getOrCreate(entityB)
```

Which return the entity B if is already exist, or create it.

But, there is no other solution ? 
cascadeType.merge is not supposed to fix this kind of problem ?

Comment: Either don't use `CascadeType.PERSIST` on `A.fieldOfTypeB`, or use `session.merge()` instead of `save`. - I also strongly recommend to use JPA (`EntityManager`) instead of proprietary hibernate APIs (`Session`,...).

Comment: So what can I use instead of `CascadeType.PERSIST` ? because I want that hibernate persist B if he doesn't exists. 
I tried with `session.merge(a)' but it's not work anymore.

Comment: To cascade the *merge* operation across relations, you'll need to declare the field with `CascadeType.MERGE`.